# What is the function of Duplo part# 38507 RAIL ACCESSORY, NO. 4

Tags: piece-information, trains, duplo

[image: #6225519]

Can someone explain to me what [38507: RAIL ACCESSORY, NO. 4](https://rebrickable.com/parts/38507/rail-accessory-no-4/4/) (#6225519) is for? I've got this in the new  [Duplo Train accessory #10882](https://brickset.com/inventories/10882-1/rebrickable) and can't figure out what it does :S

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the DUPLO Action Bricks work?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/10907/how-does-the-duplo-action-bricks-work)

Answer (score 10):

[image]
It's an interactive piece that makes the train perform a cool(ish) function when it rolls over it.

[image]
The train has a sensor on the bottom that reads the piece and does the deed.

[image]
When the train reads this red one... it stops moving, which is sorta coolish  for a jealous older sibling maybe ;).

[image]
Watch 3 videos explaining all the cool possibilities.  *([1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8O62jIivqk)), ([2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M0kn_1oIP9Q)), ([3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBetTzIKaXI))*.

Comment: I guess only very new trains have this since my 10508 Deluxe Train Set V110 doesn't have the sensor. Does anyone know which train set has the sensor?

Comment: I personally don't own any DUPLO sets, so I'm just using the internet to do the friendly research.  If we have a train set in question, double check with the box art. LEGO's box art calls these funky bricks "Action Bricks".  If the box art doesn't promote the Action Brick and Interactive App feature, then it's most likely a no go.

Comment: The sensor equipped trains are sets  10874-1 and 10875-1.  This group's common set series begin with "108", so it looks like any DUPLO train set that starts with 108 seems compatible, so far...  Rest of the sets I see that have no Sensor Train,but the funky Action Bricks are 10872-1 and 10882-1.