# DUPLO cargo train 10875 blue action brick has no effect

Tags: trains, duplo, sensor-colour

I bought my daughter [Cargo Train 10875](https://www.lego.com/en-ch/product/cargo-train-10875) and it all works OK with one exception—the blue action brick has no effect. The other action bricks all have some noticeable effect.

I asked LEGO to send me a replacement blue action brick, and they did, but the new brick doesn't have any effect either.

Has anyone else had this problem? I'm wondering if the train itself is defective.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do the DUPLO Action Bricks work?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/10907/how-do-the-duplo-action-bricks-work)

Comment: Try cleaning the light sensor on the bottom of the locomotive.

Comment: Well, if sensor cleaning does not change behaviour for blue colored action brick I would suggest getting in touch with LEGO Customer Service again asking for locomotive base replacement. It might be that the unit itself has some issues.

Comment: I cleaned the light sensor on the bottom of the locomotive, but it made no difference. I will contact LEGO about replacing the locomotive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the locomotive unit itself must have been faulty. I returned the entire set for a full refund and ordered a new one, and the locomotive from the new set performs the expected action when it passes over the blue brick.

I’m glad I went to the effort because the action triggered by the blue brick is probably the most interesting of all of them.